# Datetime On Django on models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I just wanna ask if there is a documentation on the datatype for the Django or you can give me the specific datatype to get a datetime field on models.

The latter is preferable because I have a turtle and unstable net which makes surfing a little hard.

This is my current class and

```
    class Client(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40) 
        contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        email = models.EmailField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.first_name
```

I want to add a birthday field.

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

Comment: I'm really am sorry is so slow. but thanks man. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can work with:

```
 birthday = models.DateField()
```